# How to cancel the ngrx effect if the store has already the cached data?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-http, ngrx-effects

In my Angular app, I want to stop calling the server using the `ProductService` which has `http` if the store has already the data.

This is what I currently have. I get a stream from the store and check whether the store has products. If the store has already products, return that data. Otherwise proceed the flow, get the `categoryId`, call the server using the `ProductService` and return the data.

Am I doing the effect correctly?

```
loadProducts$ = createEffect(
    () => ({ debounce = 300, scheduler = asyncScheduler } = {}) =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ProductActions.LoadProducts),
        debounceTime(debounce, scheduler),
        switchMap(() => this.ProductStore.pipe(select(ProductSelectors.selectAllProducts))),
        switchMap((Products) => {
          if (Products.length != 0) {
            return ProductActions.LoadProductsSuccess({ Products });
          }

          return of(ProductActions.LoadProductsCancelled({ Products }));
        }),
        switchMap(() => this.store.pipe(select(fromRoots.getCategory))),
        switchMap((category) =>
          this.ProductService.getProducts(category.categoryId).pipe(
            map(Products => (ProductActions.LoadProductsSuccess({ Products }))),
            catchError(err => of(ProductActions.LoadProductsFailed(err))
            )
          ))));
```

Comment: Generally that works.The idea is to handle it within your pipe stream through the use of conditional statements before dispatching the Success/Error action!

Comment: Why not use the withLatestFrom selector to see if it is already in your store? If so, return the data from store, if not call the endpoint

Comment: I modified the effect and posted as an answer. It surprised me that I could not use ```switchMap(() => this.store.select(ProductSelectors.selectAllProducts)``` in the place of ```withLatestFrom``` The effect was getting called in an infinite loop though the effect was initiated only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the effect per Flignats suggestion, and is follows:

```
  loadProducts$ = createEffect(
    () => ({ debounce = 300, scheduler = asyncScheduler } = {}) =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ProductActions.LoadProducts),
        debounceTime(debounce, scheduler),
        withLatestFrom(
          this.store.select(ProductSelectors.selectAllProducts),
          this.rootState.select(fromRoots.getcategory),
        ),
        switchMap(([action, existingProducts, category]) => {

          if (existingProducts.length > 0) {
            return of(ProductActions.LoadProductsSuccess({ Products: existingProducts }));
          }

          return this.ProductService.getProducts(category.categoryId).pipe(
            map(newProducts => (ProductActions.LoadProductsSuccess({ Products: newProducts }))),
            catchError(err => of(ProductActions.LoadProductsFailed(err)))
          )
        })));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition effect like this

```
@Effect()
    getMemberInfo$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<memberAction.GetMember>(
        memberAction.MemberActionTypes.GetMember
    )
    .switchMap((action) => {
        let obs;
        this.store.select(getMember).take(1).subscribe(res => {
            const existsInStore = res.length > 0;
            if (existsInStore) {
              let member: IMember = res.find(x => x.id === action.payload);
              member = {
                  ...member
              };

              obs = new memberAction.GeMemberSuccess(member);
            } else {
              obs = this.memberService.getMember(action.payload)
                .map(member => {
                    return new memberAction.GeMemberSuccess(member);
                });
            }

        });
        return obs;
    });
```

Comment: Using a ```subscribe``` inside the switchMap is an anti-pattern.